# What does "unknown command" mean in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

While chatting with another user just type /some text in Pidgin. It shows "unknown command". What does it mean? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry i found the answer . actually the acceptable commands in pidgin are buzz, clear, clearall, debug, help, me, ping, say

Check here :

```
   Use "/help <command>" for help on a specific command.
    The following commands are available in this context:
    buzz, clear, clearall, debug, help, me, ping, say.
```

Comment: This `/somecommand` syntax initially appeared in IRC, and now can be found in almost all chat and IM clients (including even Skype).

Comment: ya .thats true :-)

Comment: If your message begins with a slash, Pidgin will interpret it as a command. Use `/say MSG` to work around this (where `MSG` is the message beginning with a slash).